# Capturing OnEnter() in Winforms TextBox specifically via TAB only

Tags: winforms

I want to capture when a control is TABed to.

I thought it might be easier to handle when a control is NOT entered via mouse click. I was hoping that OnMouseDown() happened before OnEnter() so I could set a flag but it doesn't. I guess I could check mouse button state in OnEnter() but that seems like a kludge.

I don't think I care about what happens when focus is set programmatically. The default, I guess.

Any ideas?

Comment: What problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to distinguish them? That sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me.

Comment: I need to select all when tabbing so default behavior is to auto-replace text with new input but mousing still behaves normally - i.e. edits text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is awkward to do but you can technically spy on the input events generate by Windows before they are dispatched.  Have you main form implement the IMessageFilter interface and look at the message number.  For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        this.FormClosed += delegate { Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this); };
    }

    public enum InputEvent { Unknown, Keyboard, Mouse };
    public static InputEvent LastInputEvent { get; private set; }

    bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg >= 0x100 && m.Msg <= 0x109) LastInputEvent = InputEvent.Keyboard;
        if (m.Msg >= 0x200 && m.Msg <= 0x20A) LastInputEvent = InputEvent.Mouse;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        textBox2.BackColor = LastInputEvent == InputEvent.Mouse ? Color.AliceBlue : Color.Yellow;
    }
```

I can't think of an obvious failure mode, there might be one.  Strange request btw.